# Are probes such as the Fifa World Cup corruption probe common place in other sports?

Tags: football

The recent ruling passed by the judge, Hans Joachim-Eckhart chose to ignore the recommendations provided by Michael Garcia (Garcia, an American lawyer, spent two years trying to compile the report), and cleared certain nations of corruption charges.

Those nations who refused to cooperate (partially or completely) or destroyed/misplaced all evidence were cleared of all wrong doing while nations who cooperated fully were the subject of the criticism.

"numerous materially incomplete and erroneous representations", 
"the interpretation of the Garcia report is not a fair one, according to Garcia himself, it's pretty ugly for FIFA if the person who did the inquiry says the judge hasn't properly reflected his inquiry "  - Greg Dyke F.A. Chairman

My question is this,

Is this kind of behaviour commonplace in other sports that consider themselves a global brand?

global brand - I would consider American Football, IAAF, FIA, WTF, to name a few - sports where interest far exceeds local boundaries, exposure is global and famous names are revered even for young children in distant countrys (smaller, localised bodies have very different influencing factors and I've no doubt the types of behavior I question do exist, but to Global Brands where image and perception are key I wouldn't think this behaviour was tolerated or acceptable)

kind of behaviour - performing an investigation on themselves and choosing to ignore findings and recommendations - even choosing to penalise those within the organisation that had the audacity to have suggested an investigation in the first place

I don't believe this to be opinion based, but I understand a persons answer can be prejudiced by there own beliefs. (and that can be said for many questions on this site and its sister ones - not every league has goal line technology).

As an example,

The FIA, or whatever name Formula 1's governing body was using at the time, seems to lurch between crisis to crisis whenever the Concorde Agreement gets mentioned, but historically it seems it's problems predominantly arise from external factors/organisations rather than from within themselves (Although I accept it's current problems lie within it). I freely admit I am not an expert on the matter, and my investigating (into F1) only seems to find murky waters that leave me more confused. Perhaps to someone more knowledgeable examples and evidence could be easily presented.

I have left out nations names involved so as to avoid being deemed a patriotic, jingoistic ranter. I'm more interested to know is this behaviour commonplace in other sports.

I hope this question is well received and meets little scorn, and I hope to have a better understanding as to the condition of the pinnacle of our sports as the first generation of the 21st century approaches adulthood.
After all its competitors are held on such a high pedestal by so many of us.

Comment: I'm Australian and I'm absolutely disgusted that tax dollars were spent on bribery. Not a single politician is making any noise about it over here.